# How to get image tag src value from json object

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

In WordPress comment API i want a image tag src value through ReactJS. So i tried to get value as `{ item.author_avatar_urls[24] }` but in the front the img tag is not properly fetched, it look like this:

`&lt;img src="http://localhost/project/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/auhtor.png" width="49" height="50" alt="admin" class="avatar avatar-50 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-50 alignnone photo" /&gt;`

How can i get the proper img src value from JSON object ?

My json is as below image
[image: JSON image]

Comment: You can't render HTML from a string by default in React since all that is rendered will be escaped. You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) if you need to render HTML from a string, but be sure you are in control of the string or a malicious user might exploit it.

Comment: what is "proper img src value" ? you want what is inside the src prop?

Comment: yes i want only src value. It is a img path. 
So that i can use like this <img src={item.avatar_url[24]} className="img" alt="image">